# Initializing a pointer in a function

Tags: c, pointers

Example structure:

```
struct MyList {
    struct myElem *head;
};
```

---

I'm new to pointers. And I get a few things already but not the following.

What is the difference between those two options?

```
struct MyList *newEmptyList() {
    struct MyList list;
    list.head = NULL;
    return &list;
}
```

```
struct MyList *newEmptyList() {
    struct MyList *list;
    list->head = NULL;
    return list;
}
```

Comment: `return &list;` = *undefined behavior* for anyone that dereferences that returned address. `list` no longer exists after `newEmptyList` returns. And the second example `list->head = NULL;` dereferences an indeterminate pointer, more *undefined behavior*. You need to review your reference materials on pointers. Ultimately the differences aren't as important as their similarities. Both are dreadfully wrong. However, the former packages up some impending UB doom for the caller to trip over, whilst the latter takes that bull by the horns and executes it straight away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are wrong:

Here you return the pointer to a local variable, but once the function `newEmptyList` is terminated, `list` no longer exists:

```
struct MyList *newEmptyList() {
    struct MyList list;
    list.head = NULL;
    return &list;
}
```

---

This is wrong because `list` (which is a pointer) points nowhere and therefore you cannot dereference it like here: `list->head = NULL;`

```
struct MyList *newEmptyList() {
    struct MyList *list;
    list->head = NULL;
    return list;
}
```

You probably want this:

```
struct MyList *newEmptyList() {
    struct MyList *list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    list->head = NULL;
    return list;
}
```

`malloc` allocates memory for your `list` pointer. After the call to `malloc`, `list` points to some valid memory.

Comment: "*This is wrong because list (which is a pointer) points nowhere*", it is not initialized to NULL. So it can point to any address.

Answer (score 2):

Both cause undefined-behaviour:

```
struct MyList *newEmptyList() {
    struct MyList list;
    list.head = NULL;
    return &list;
}
```

```
struct MyList *newEmptyList() {
    struct MyList *list;
    list->head = NULL;
    return list;
}
```

In the first one, you are returning the address of a local variable which is on the stack. As when the function returns, **accessing** the values previously on that stack is undefined behavior. It doesn't cause undefined behavior until you dereference the pointer returned.

In the second one:

1. Pointers not assigned to a memory address is dangerous to use. Causes undefined behavior
2. `list->head` dereferences `list` which causes undefined behavior straight away, as the pointer doesn't point to a usable memory address, and you are trying to write to that memory address...

The correct way to do this is:

```
struct MyList *newEmptyList() {
    struct MyList *list = malloc(sizeof(struct MyList));
    list->head = NULL;
    return list;
}
```

`malloc()` allocates memory on the heap and returns the memory address of the start of the allocated memory.

### Pointers

Pointers in C are basically variables that hold the address of other variables.